# SQL Declaration error

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I execute the SQL below I get the error "Must declare the table variable "@ID"."  But I am declarring it so whats wrong?

```
DECLARE @ID uniqueidentifier
SET @ID = NEWID()

SELECT pcx_vacancyassociationId
INTO      pcx_vacancyassociationBase 
FROM @ID

SELECT pcx_candidate_to_pcx_vacancyId, .pcx_candidateid, pcx_vacancyid

INTO  pcx_vacancyassociationExtensionBase
FROM @ID,  pcx_candidate_to_pcx_vacancyBase.pcx_candidateid, pcx_candidate_to_pcx_vacancyBase.pcx_vacancyid
```

Comment: Looks to me as if you are declaring it as a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, not as a table variable.

Comment: Where do you wish the `@ID` variable's value to go? If you want it to be inserted into the tables specified in your `SELECT .. INTO` queries, put it in the *SELECT list*, not the FROM clause.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned the problem is that it's not a table variable, not sure what you're going for, but perhaps you mean to insert the value?:

```
INSERT INTO pcx_vacancyassociationBase  (pcx_vacancyassociationId)
VALUES (@ID)
```

Not entirely sure which fields you want, but you can do a SELECT INTO:

```
SELECT @ID as 'pcx_vacancyassociationId', pcx_candidate_to_pcx_vacancyId, pcx_candidateid, pcx_vacancyid
INTO  pcx_vacancyassociationExtensionBase
FROM Table
```

Or INSERT INTO:

```
INSERT INTO pcx_vacancyassociationBase  
    SELECT @ID as 'pcx_vacancyassociationId', pcx_candidate_to_pcx_vacancyId, pcx_candidateid, pcx_vacancyid
    INTO  pcx_vacancyassociationExtensionBase
    FROM Table
```

In both versions the @ID will be the same for every row, if you want random value for every row then don't use the variable, just use NEWID() in the SELECT clause.

Comment: Is there a way to mix the values.  I mean one from the variable as in your example and the other two from the table?

Comment: The source tables are pcx_candidate_to_pcx_vacancyBase.pcx_candidateid, pcx_candidate_to_pcx_vacancyBase.pcx_vacancyid the new row I'm inserting needs three keys a new guid and these to foreign keys

Comment: Ah, then you need to JOIN the tables in your FROM clause.

Comment: If you add a sample of your table structure to your question that would help.

Comment: I have  tables one is empty and only has 3 fields candidateid, vacancyId and it's primary key pcx_candidate_to_pcx_vacancyId I need to get the data from a second table that has the matching fields but I also have to create and insert a guid at the same time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32104/discussion-between-user1842828-and-goat-co)

Answer (score 1):

It's because @ID is not a table; it's a scalar value, a uniqueidentifier.  You can't use scalar values in a FROM clause.

Comment: Is there a way I can generate the guid @ID and insert it with the other data?

Answer (score 0):

In order to declare a table variable, you have to actually declare it like a table.

Like so:

```
DECLARE @ProductTotals TABLE 
(
  Field1 <type>, 
  Field2 <type>
)
```